# RPC JSONP error object conventions

Tags: object, exception, error-handling, jsonp

Im building a php json(p) rpc server and currently i am stuck with not finding sufficient information on how to handle/respond if a jsonp call throws an error inside the called function/method. With json rpc 2.0 its well documented - with jsonp its not. how to return errors from the application level of the service called?

Suppose a call like `/service.php?var=test&callback=jsonpCallback` is requested. in a positive case the result would be something like `jsonpCallback({"result": "test"})`. Suppose on the application level an exception is thrown? what do i return and how?

Do i return an error object inside the callback? or just a json (custom) error object as string? If there is something like an jsonp error object convention where to find it?

Does make sense to allow for a custom error callback in the GET request which can be called like: `/service.php?var=test&callback=jsonpCallback&errorCallback=jsonpErrorCallback`

Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use an error object, but that means you have to implement an explicit handling of such inside the normal code. That can be annoying. Instead have a try returning a standard http error code and reacting to that (which you have to implement anyway...).

Comment: ok but there is no standard behaviour or specs for the error object itself?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.